# Is inheritance possible in django when the models have same fields but different help_text

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 models that have the exact same fields. The only difference is that the help text for each is different. Is. there a way I can remove this repetition e.g using inheritance or something?
Here are my 2 classes

```
class IgnoreListGsheet(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="The key of the Google Sheet holding the ignore list.")
    worksheet_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="The name of the workspace containing the ignore list")
    column_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="The column name containing the ignore list.")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key


class RespondListGsheet(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="The key of the Google Sheet holding the respond to list.")
    worksheet_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="The name of the workspace containing the respond to accounts")
    column_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="The column name containing the respond to accounts.")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

Comment: You could just have one modal, and use a boolean Respond field to flag which help text you should use, then have a couple functions to return the help text value you'd want for an attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```py
class BaseSheet(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text = "")
    worksheet_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="")
    column_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key


class IgnoreListGsheet(BaseSheet):
    class Meta:
        help_texts = {'key': 'foo', 'worksheet_name': 'bar', 'column_name': 'baz',}
```

Even though this is the solution for forms, it might translate into models. If it doesn't, then you might have to add this to your forms and render them instead of the model itself.

Comment: It doesn't directly translate but the second recommendation works. Thank you.